# How do I call a URL without loading the page called?

Tags: javascript, url, firefox-addon, xul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Extract/Retrieve source code given URL in Firefox extention (javascript or XUL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965944/how-to-extract-retrieve-source-code-given-url-in-firefox-extention-javascript-o)

In JavaScript code of a Firefox extension I want to send data as parameters using a URL but I don't want the currently loaded page to be replaced. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure. i tried...
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url ,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
With those lines and the correct url,it didn't work,i don't know what i did wrong or is my understanding of XUL's DOM to blame.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can simply call :

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Of course you need to replace test.php with the URL you call and { name: "John", time: "2pm" } with the data you want to send over.

Source : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

T.